# how to get spcecial charecter input and store in char or string variable? special characters means © or ž

Tags: c++

```
// Microsoft visual studio 2010

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char password;
    string strPassword;

    cin >> password; // only for single character 
    cin >> strPassword // for string storage

    /* 1. but when I give input © it will store as single character c, not as ©.
    I want to store it as © in my variable 'password' or 'strPassword' so  that I can compare it with my pre-stored password
    2. I also want to know about stdint.h 
   what is it ? why we need it and how it helps us (especially for streaming).
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30197758/how-can-i-make-unicode-iostream-i-o-work-in-both-windows-and-unix-land for a general fix. I hesitate to close this question as a duplicate because my q+a covers much more.

Comment: Read more about text encodings. C type `char` is not actually a character, it is just a single byte integer number. Usually it is used as a character of some character table or as a part of some string encoded with some rules. For example, if string encoding is UTF-8, the © representation requires 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first question about text encodings, you need the program to assume the same text encoding as it receives via input. One way to do that in Windows is to check what your **ANSI codepage** is, e.g. via commmand `wmic os get codeset`. For example, a US or Norwegian will get 1252, the Windows ANSI Western codepage.

Then configure your console window to that, e.g. include

```
system( "chcp 1252" );
```

at the start of your program.

More generally you will need to use Unicode to deal with a larger character set. See my Q+A [“How can I make Unicode iostream i/o work in both Windows and Unix-land?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30197758/how-can-i-make-unicode-iostream-i-o-work-in-both-windows-and-unix-land). Hopefully it's not been invalidated by compiler evolution.

---

Regarding the second question about `stdint.h`, that I suggest that you just google. It's surely a duplicate on SO. And SO is not a site for tutorials.