# Visual Studio doesn't print the correct nordic characters

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, character

I tried to print out `"Text här"`, and it printed out `"Text hôr"`.
`"ö"` turns into `"+"` and `"å"` turns into `"Ô"`.

Here is the whole code.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
std::cout << "Text här";
return 0;
}
```

I use visual studio 2015. What could be causing this and how would I get it fixed?

Comment: Probably you can find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371012/how-do-i-print-utf-8-from-c-console-application-on-windows

Comment: The default configuration of a console on Windows to this day is still based on choices that were sensible back in 1982.  Very hard to fix, too many business-critical apps assume it is still 1982.  Just tell your text editor about it.  In VS do so with File > Save As > arrow on the Save button > Code page 437.

Comment: Title should actually be 'My program doesn't print the correct nordic characters'

Comment: @HansPassant: Lying to the compiler about the source encoding, is very bad advice. In so many ways.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a mismatch between the character encoding used in your executable, and the one used in the console window.

You can change the console window's character encoding via the `chcp` command.

You can issue that manually or e.g. in your program:

```
system( "chcp 1252 >nul" );
```

---

To avoid most of the encoding issues and handle international characters in general, you can use Unicode i/o.

However, the C++ standard library's support is next to non-existent, which means using platform-specific functionality, and secondly, the console windows are essentially limited to the Basic Multilingual Plane of Unicode, corresponding to original 16-bit Unicode, because of the original API design.

In practice these issues, and others, mean that there's a difference between beginner's exploratory code, and professional portable code.

---

You may find the following useful: ([How can I make Unicode iostream i/o work in both Windows and Unix-land?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30197758/how-can-i-make-unicode-iostream-i-o-work-in-both-windows-and-unix-land))